# parse through table and put it back together

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get rid of the HTML element in my data, so I parse through it with BeautifulSoup. But I'm confused about how to get it back together after I loop through it.

this is my dataset looks like:
[image]

I parse through the table and get rid of the HTML element in it with this code:

```
testDataset = tags_ALL2
testDataset['description'] = testDataset['description'].astype(str)
testDataset2 = testDataset['description']
for url in testDataset['description']:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
    row = {}
    for j in soup.get_text():
        row = "\t".join(j)
    return row
```

In the end, I want to get all the parsed text and get it together inside the description for each row.
But, my code somehow recognizes the **return** statement as a syntax error.

can anyone help me please?

**EDITED:**
it works fine with this code from @Shweta Chandel:

```
def clean(text):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
    return soup.get_text()

testDataset['description'] = testDataset['description'].apply(lambda x: clean(x))
```

Comment: Please post the correctly indented code.

Comment: @ShwetaChandel fixed it. sorry. but the return row is there I think, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share that dataframe/table (or atleast the code that generates that table). And I'm not sure what your expected/wanted output should be.

Comment: You shouldn't be returning something while being inside a loop unless there is a condition. Let the loop finish and then return the value and make it a function so that it can return something.

Comment: @ShwetaChandel I moved the return row one indent back, but still doesn't work

Comment: You can return something if it is in a function. Is the code posted above inside a function? Instead of return, try print.

Comment: @ShwetaChandel i tried with:

**for j in soup.get_text():**
        **row = ''.join(j)**
        **print(row)**

but the results is not a one-line string, but instead new-line character

Comment: I think instead of dict, you should create a list outside and then append in it. Please debug your code. See what is the value in j. And every time, row variable gets updated which defeats the purpose because dict is a data structure and meant to store multiple values.

Comment: @ShwetaChandel I tried with dict and list both. but I think that's not the main problem now. The problem is that it cannot be concatenated in one string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def clean(text):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
    return soup.get_text()

testDataset['description'] = testDataset['description'].apply(lambda x: clean(x))
```

Comment: @ZakiulFahmiJailani Can you accept and upvote it if it helped?

Comment: i have little reputation. i cast a vote but not change the public display @Shweta Chandel